# How to avoid points being cut off at the edges of the chart

Tags: altair

Using the default configuration, points in Altair plots are sometimes cut off at the edges of a  chart (here left and top):
[Example Altair chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLptm.png)

This is the code that produces the chart:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "X": [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2],
    "Y": [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 2.9, 2.98, 2.99]
})
chart = alt.Chart(
    df,
).mark_point().encode(
    x='X',
    y='Y',
).properties(
    width=400,
    height=350
).interactive()
chart
```

I have read about `clip`, `clamp` and `padding`, but they do not fit my needs.
With `clip` users of the chart (when it is interactive) can move the plot outside the chart window, which I would like to prevent. `clamp` is a different form of visualization, also not what I want here. And with `padding` I get inconsistent results with the data points then sometimes being very far away from the axes.

So my question is, how can I globally configure Altair to always show all points in full?
Hopefully, there is a way to achieve this that does not require manually setting the scale domains every time.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Kind regards,
Axel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `.interactive` I believe you would get what you want:

[image]

If you click the three dot action menu on the two charts (with and without "interactive") and select to view it in the Vega editor, you will see that `interactive` adds this section:

```
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "param_2",
      "select": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x", "y"]},
      "bind": "scales"
    }
  ],
```

There is nothing here that is controlled by altair but rather by Vega-Lite, so I would raise an issue there to ask why the addition of params (or maybe specifically scale-bound params), changes the display of the points